# JavaScript - Modal - Close image by clicking anywhere outside the image

Tags: javascript, html, image, modal-dialog

I have a responsive image gallery, where you can click on an image, and it will pop up as a modal, that shows the full view of the image.

However, currently, the only way to close the modal is using the 'X' button in the top right hand corner

What I would like, is to be able to close the modal by clicking anywhere off the image. i.e. on the black background around the image

I have attached a fiddle as an example of what my image gallery is currently like

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/eoansv83/2/

HTML:

```
 <div class="responsive">
  <div class="gImg">
  <img src="test.jpg">
  <div class="desc">example 1</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gImg">
  <img src="test.jpg">
  <div class="desc">example 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// Get all images and insert the clicked image inside the modal
// Get the content of the image description and insert it inside the modal image caption
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
 images[i].onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  modalImg.alt = this.alt;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close .

You need to add an event listener to modal , so that on click,it update it's `display` property to `none`

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
modal.addEventListener('click',function(){
this.style.display="none";
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/eoansv83/3/)

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Try this.Hope it will help to you.....**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#img01').click(function(e){

              //e.preventDefault();
              $(this).show();  
              e.stopPropagation();

            });

});
```

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iyyappan13391/eoansv83/4/)

Comment: Hi, that works, thanks for this!  Quick question, any chance you know how I can smooth out the closing of the image? Currently, it closes the image too quickly, and as a result looks quite rough. Do you know how I could slow this down, so it closes the modal more smoothly?

Comment: For smoothing we have to add some animation classes or js predefined animation function.If you found the answer.Please vote me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ignoreClickOnImg = document.getElementById('gImg');
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var isClick = ignoreClickOnImg.contains(e.target);
    if (!isClick) {
         modal.display = "none";   // or write what you want
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.